# Using shared_ptr and glutInit causes segmentation fault

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, shared-ptr, glut

Having asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33855611/defining-shared-ptr-causes-segfault-cmake) before I tried out a lot of things and found out that the problem has to do with glutInit. Take the following code examples:
main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include<GL/glut.h>
using namespace std;
int main(int argcp, char **argv)
{
    shared_ptr<double> abc;
    glutInit(&argcp,argv);
    cout<<"Hello!"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

compiled with:

> g++ -std=c++11 -g -Wall -o appx main.cpp -lGL -lGLU -lglut

cause the executable to instantly crash (no "Hello!" output) with segfault using g++ 5.2.1, ubuntu 15.10

Just commenting out the line

```
shared_ptr<double> abc;
```

will fix the crash.

Since i want to use shared_ptr and glut in a project I would like to know how this can be fixed or what causes the crash.

**Edit 1:**
GDB trace:

```
#0  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007ffff33fb6fd in init () at dlerror.c:177
#2  _dlerror_run (operate=operate@entry=0x7ffff33fb0e0 <dlsym_doit>,args=args@entry=0x7fffffffde00) at dlerror.c:129
#3  0x00007ffff33fb148 in __dlsym (handle=<optimized out>, name=optimized out>) at dlsym.c:70
#4  0x00007ffff6fa2e1e in ?? () from /usr/lib/nvidia-352/libGL.so.1
#5  0x00007ffff6f4db47 in ?? () from /usr/lib/nvidia-352/libGL.so.1
#6  0x00007ffff7de957d in call_init (l=0x7ffff7fc59c8,argc=argc@entry=1,         argv=argv@entry=0x7fffffffdf58, env=env@entry=0x7fffffffdf68)at dl-init.c:58
#7  0x00007ffff7de96cb in call_init (env=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>, argc=<optimized out>, l=<optimized out>) at dl-init.c:30
#8  _dl_init (main_map=0x7ffff7ffe188, argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdf58, env=0x7fffffffdf68) at dl-init.c:120
#9  0x00007ffff7dd9d0a in _dl_start_user () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#10 0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
#11 0x00007fffffffe2c8 in ?? ()
#12 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31579243/segmentation-fault-before-main-when-using-glut-and-stdstring) looks related..

Comment: Please run in gdb and give us the back-trace.

Comment: Can't reproduce on Fedora 22 with gcc 5.1.1.

Comment: I added the gdb output but it does not seem to help much here.

Comment: Sorry messed up the backtrace. Now it shows more.

Comment: Do you get the samme issue if you compile/link with the `-pthread` flag ?

Comment: Yes thanks that solves the problem! :) The explanation on the question linked in the fist comment makes it clear.

Answer (score 1):

As posted in the comments the problem was similar to the problem posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31579243/segmentation-fault-before-main-when-using-glut-and-stdstring).

The solution is adding:

```
 -lpthread
```

to the compiler flags!
Thanks a lot!